# RequireJS does not load modules after updating dom

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, requirejs

I have two separate (Angular) apps, and want to navigate from one app to the other (because of modularity and not having the ownership of both apps it isn't one big Angular app).

As I want to avoid page reloads (including visible flickring) I fetch the complete content of app 2 using ajax when I want to transition to that app from app 1. After that I replace the complete DOM with the newly fetched content like this:

`document.replaceChild(newNode, document.documentElement);`

where newNode is the Node holding the new content. The new content looks roughly like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="/lib/requirejs/require.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script>
        require(['apptwo/app']);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
</body>
```

The DOM looks exactly the same as when I redirect to app 2 (and with a normal redirect it works flawless), but unfortunately requirejs refuses to load my app somehow when I replace the DOM instead:

`AppSwitcher.js:101 Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: apptwo/app`

Does anyone has a clue why RequireJS can't load the module this way?

Edit: The content of apptwo/app looks like this:

```
/// <amd-dependency path="angular"/>
/// <amd-dependency path="angular-ui-router"/>
define(["require", "exports", 'angular'], function (require, exports, angular) {
    'use strict';
    var ngModule = angular.module('apptwo', ['ui.router']);
    //declaration of some controllers and such
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['apptwo']);
});
```

Comment: could you put the content of apptwo/app. At least the requirements line? I can't see where the angular is loaded.

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo, added that in my question, see above.

Comment: Who resolves the "ui.router"? I use something like module(..., [ require('uiRouter') ] and then, on uiRouter.js, I return 'ui.router' (using define(...), of course)

Comment: another tip is monitor the browser network log to verify the sequence of loads

Comment: Resolving ui.router and other needed deps in done using the amd-dependency combined with my requireJS config (which is in main.js and loads correctly).

I already monitored the network log, and require.js and main.js are perfectly loaded, but apptwo/app not. Looks like RequireJS doesn't even try to load it...

Comment: Maybe require consider that module as loaded before. Take a look at require.undef

Comment: After some digging I discover that requireJS actually tries to load the module, but the generated script node is somehow appended to the 'head' section of the old DOM which I replaced with a new one... So even after replacing the DOM and loading RequireJS again RequireJS somehow holds some references to the old DOM. Now see how I can re-initialize RequireJS itself..

Comment: probably it's on a global variable, DOM independent.